# Why can I create a new user, but when I immediately attempt to authenticate with their credentials, I fail?

Tags: asp.net-membership

I create a new user, approve them, then immediately attempt to authenticate *with the credentials I just used to create the user*...and get "false" back the Authenticate method.

```
string username = "me";
string password = "mypassword";
string email = "me@domain.com";

Membership.CreateUser(username, password, email);

currentUser = Membership.GetUser(username);
currentUser.IsApproved = true;

bool isAuthenticated = FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, password);
```

I checked the database table -- the user is created with that username, password, and email. According to the database table, they are approved.

Yet, the Authenticate method still returns false.

Comment: This is odd. You do have other users who weren't created on the fly and who can log in, we assume. And the new users you create in this manner can log in later?

Comment: Is this happening when you run in Visual Studio (using IIS or Cassini?) or when you run it from a web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the UpdateUser method after you change their approved status...

```
   Membership.UpdateUser(currentUser);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.isapproved.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but no luck.  We checked the database previously, and the Approved column in there has always indicated that they've been approved successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Likely that the authentication mechanism is using a different data store under the covers that has yet to be cascade to.